# Получаю ответ с сервера не в UTF-8 кодировке, как это исправить?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, mysqli, клиент-сервер

С сервера получаю ответ, где русские слова заменяются на подобное: `\u0414\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0439`

Как может на самом сервере что-то нужно прописать, чтобы к БД подключалось в UTF-8 режиме и получало данные как надо. Или уже со стороны приложения, которое ответ с сервера получает, что-то нужно добавить, чтобы конвертировать эти номера в символы?

Сервер у меня на PHP, приложение на Android Studio.

Вот фрагмент сервера, который тестировал:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {

    require 'db_config.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($con)); 

    $login = $_GET['login'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password'");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $user = array();
            $user["_id"] = $result["_id"];
            $user["login"] = $result["login"];
            $user["password"] = $result["password"];
            $user["email"] = $result["email"];
            $user["money"] = $result["money"];
            $user["record"] = $result["record"];

            $response["user"] = array();
            array_push($response["user"], $user);

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Здесь фрагмент кода, который принимает ответ с сервера:
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                urlConnection.connect();

```
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }
```

Comment: Необходимо указать кодировку для созданного соединения. Попробуйте добавить это: `mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");`. Должно помочь. Мануал для ознакомления [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Comment: Да, я недавно пробовал, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Тогда в Java приложении попробуйте  заменить `"utf-8"` на `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`.

Comment: Тоже не помогло

Comment: А кодировка базы у вас точно UTF-8? Возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076988/php-json-encode-json-decode-utf-8) или [это](https://toster.ru/q/6050) поможет.

Comment: У меня управление БД через phpmyadmin и там в графе "Сравнение" каждой таблицы стоит "utf8_unicode_ci" и у самой таблицы "Сравнение" тоже "utf8_unicode_ci". А у самого сервера "Сопоставление кодировки соединения" тоже стоит "utf8_unicode_ci"
В таблицах данные с русскими символами корректно отображаются, а не непонятной кириллицей, как бывает при шалостях кодировки.

Comment: А что не так-то? `"\u0414\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0439"` - вполне себе utf-8

Comment: `JSON.parse('"\u0414\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0439"')` -> `"Дмитрий"`

Answer (score 0):

Заработало после того, как я сделал это:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Это одно из первых, что я пробовал сделать, но я случайно эту строку не в том файле прописал, а тестировал другой, в котором все без изменений конечно оставалось...